# How do pokemon stats relate to attack power?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

**The question**: How do the stats of an individual pokemon relate to its abilities' damage?

*For example*: Let's say i have a pokemon that has 110 Atk and 100 Sp Atk. He knows 2 attacks: 1 is a Physical Attack with 80 power, and 1 is a Special Attack with 90 power. How do i determine which would deal more damage in the end?

Is the damage calculated by:

1. Adding the power to the stats (110 + 80 = 190, 100 + 90 = 190), meaning both attacks are equally powerful?
2. Are the powers a % based off of the stats (110 * 0.8 = 88, 100 * 0.9 = 90), meaning the special attack is better?
3. Some other way?

For the scope of the question, i would like to overlook things like damage boosting items, opponent's defense stats, STAB/Effectiveness, and other outside influences.

How does this work? And if too long, where can I read more about this?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but here's a link to a pokemon damage calculator in case you find it useful: https://pokemonshowdown.com/damagecalc/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bulbapedia has the [Pokemon damage formula](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Damage#Damage_formula). But the short answer is that it is multiplicative.

[image: Forumla]

Which attack is better depends on your opponent's defenses, but lets assume they have 100 in both Defense and Special Defense. You didn't specify a level, so I'm going to assume 50. Results below with differences in **bold**.

For attack = (2*50 + 10)/250 * (**110**/100) * **80** + 2 = 40.72 * Modifier
For Special Attack = (2*50 + 10)/250 * (**100**/100) * **90** + 2 = 41.6 * Modifier

This shows your special move will be slightly stronger, which is expected for multiplicative factors (For any 2 numbers adding to the same sum, you will get the largest product when they have the least difference between them)

Note that pokemon has an element of randomness in the **Modifier** , and this can result in a 15% variance in practice.

Comment: I didn't read this, but the format makes me believe what ever you tell me.

Comment: Great answer + learned a math trick as well