# Is Ditto's Transform supposed to have 0 power?

Tags: pokemon-go

I happened to catch a Ditto, but I was trainer level 7 when I caught it. My Ditto's transform stat is 0, is this normal? Will it remain 0 always, no matter the number of times I power it up?

Also, its CP is just 52, so if I use it in a gym battle, won't it faint before it even gets a chance to transform?

[image: Ditto screen shot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the Attack and Defense stats work in Pokémon GO?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275646/how-do-the-attack-and-defense-stats-work-in-pok%c3%a9mon-go)

Comment: @333-blue this is not a duplicate of that at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Transform does 0 damage. This is in line with its behavior in the core series. Ditto will use Transform at the beginning of the battle, which does no damage, but allows it to take on the moveset, appearance, and stats of the opposing Pokémon.

It's also worth noting that Transform is a *move*, not a stat. No Pokémon's *moves* will get stronger as they level up, in this game, or in the core series. The moves will do more damage, yes, but that's due to their *stats* going up with each level.

Comment: So struggle has 15. what is that 15 dps? So my magmar with attack of 100, does 100dps? And will this 15 remain constant? or increase with level?

Comment: @Akash No, DPS is damage over time. The 15 just represents the damage. Struggle is what gets used if Ditto is unable to transform. The only case where this will happen is if it is Ditto vs. Ditto.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct - transform is not a move that does damage, but instead transforms your pokemon into the one your are fighting, and takes their moves (replacing your moves).

This is unlike [Magikarp](https://pokemon.gameinfo.io/en/pokemon/129-magikarp) that has Splash (does 0 damage), and Struggle (does 15 damage), where Splash is actually a move that builds up energy so that it can use Struggle.  Unlike Magikarp, Ditto isn't actually useless!