# Should I prioritize Pokémon on their base strengths or try and shore up a weaker stat?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have two Beldum and I'm trying to decide which one to evolve into a Metagross.  Their stats are....

```
Beldum #1). 15 attack, 15 defense, 14 stamina
Beldum #2). 15 attack, 14 defense, 15 stamina
```

So they are basically identical except for one has better defense and one has better stamina (or HP).

The site gameinfo.io shows that Metagross's stats are...

```
Attack  257
Defense 247
Stamina 160
```

So it looks like its strengths are Attack and Defense.  Maybe that means I should focus on those and evolve Beldum #1?  Or should I shore up the weakness and choose Beldum #2, which has slightly better stamina?

Comment: The Minmaxer in me would say to prioritise to the Pokemon's strengths, but even still I don't know how much a one point advantage would bring to the table. Both Beldums would probably perform very similarly.

Comment: Voting to leave open. Yes, op used the magic word "should" but there is an objective answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering how small the difference is here, any effect will be barely noticeable...

...which is not going to stop me doing the maths.

[The damage formula was discussed in this answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/281558/53291) It looks complicated but the bit we need is that incoming damage is proportional to 1/defense.

The hp formula I found [here](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-stats-advanced) was a lot simpler than expected. The important part is that it's proportional to stamina.

Defense and stamina do basically the same thing- they increase the amount of incoming damage you can take without fainting. As mentioned above, damage taken is proportional to 1/defense. This means that virtual hp is proportional to defense*stamina.

IVs are added to base stats to get the total stats. Yes, they matter this little.

So, for the above:

- 15 def, 14 stam gives us 262*175. 45850 vhp
- 14 def, 15 stam gives us 261*176. 45936 vhp

The Metagross with higher stamina is 0.19% tougher. An unbelievably tiny amount.

In general, this shows that when dealing with defense vs stamina, higher IVs in your lower stat have a more noticeable effect.

The same is true of attack, but choosing attack over defense or stamina may be more situational.